# How fill in the next row of a list in a spreadsheet using a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a spreadsheet which when you press a button adds a row of data and asks for the parameters needed for the calculations, but I cant seem to get it to fill in the data in the next row down? I am a complete begginner to macros in excel and have only done very basic programming for matlab on my uni course.
My script so far is as follows:

```
Sub AddPosTol()

' AddPosTol Macro


Dim rngSeek As Range

Set rngSeek = Range("B1")

While rngSeek <> ""
    'If the cell isn't empty, drop down one row:
    rngSeek = rngSeek.Offset(1, 0)
End

With rngSeek.Offset(0, 1)
   With .Font
       .Name = "Solid Edge ANSI1 Symbols"
       .Size = 11
       .Value = 1
   End With                                            <--added this

End With

'don't need to call Range() around rngSeek - it is already a range type

rngSeek.Offset(0, 3) = "=RC[-1]"
rngSeek.Offset(0, 4) = "0"

With rngSeek.Offset(1, 1)
    .Font.Bold = True                <--don't really need a With if only one statement
End With

'can use a With statement here if you want:

With rngSeek

    .Offset(1, 1) = "X value"
    .Offset(2, 1) = "Y Value"

    .Offset(0, 4) = "=2*SQRT((R[1]C[-3]-R[1]C)^2+(R[2]C[-3]-R[2]C)^2)"
    .Offset(0, 5) = "=2*SQRT((R4C3-R[1]C)^2+(R5C3-R[2]C)^2)"
    .Offset(0, 6) = "=2*SQRT((R[1]C[-3]-R[1]C)^2+(R[2]C[-3]-R[2]C)^2)"
    .Offset(0, 7) = "=2*SQRT((R[1]C[-3]-R[1]C)^2+(R[2]C[-3]-R[2]C)^2)"
    .Offset(0, 8) = "=2*SQRT((R4C3-R[1]C)^2+(R5C3-R[2]C)^2)"

    .Offset(0, 2) = (InputBox("Insert Positional Tolerance Diametre"))
    .Offset(1, 2) = (InputBox("Insert X value on drawing"))
    .Offset(2, 2) = (InputBox("Insert Y value on drawing"))

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: OK basically for every call to `With...` you need a matching `End With`. See edits to your post

Comment: But as far as i can tell i have done that?

Comment: Well i realised what id done, but now when i try run it it has a problem with using .value?

Comment: Ahh OK sorry I didn't notice before (I wasn't looking for it) - .value is not a sub-method of .font. So take `.value = 1` from outside the `With .Font` block and put it after the `End With`, so it is a direct child of `With rngSeek.Offset(0, 1)`. `.Value` is a method of a range object.

Comment: THanks very much for you help! Im getting paid for you work i apologise for that haha
Well it put the first value in the correct box which is a start, then it seems to crash my excel.

Comment: Try stepping through the code one line at a time using F8 to see where it hangs, then maybe post a new question? Try removing the loop and putting the line in that you found on the Microsoft site - loops can sometimes cause crashes if they never exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm going to refactor your code a bit to make it more readable, and try and answer your question too.

Firstly, I believe that `lastrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count` will return the **number of rows in the worksheet**, not the number of rows you have currently filled in. When I ran that line I got back 1048576! To find the first *empty* row, we need to find a column that will definitely have a value filled in for each row; then, cycle down that column looking for an empty cell: this is your first empty row:

```
Dim rngSeek as range

set rngSeek = Range("A1") <--your starting cell

While rngSeek <> ""
    'If the cell isn't empty, drop down one row:
    rngSeek = rngSeek.Offset(1, 0)
Wend

'rngSeek is now sitting at the first row that has a blank in column A
```

So this technique will find us the first row we are looking for. Then, we just populate that row with the data. You can leverage other elements from the code snippet above to make things easier when updating: specifically, the `.offset` method:

Your code:

```
With rngSeek.offset(0, 2)
    With .Font
        .Name = "Solid Edge ANSI1 Symbols"
        .Size = 11
    End With

    .value = 1
End With

'repeat for all cells: no need to select them first, just use .offset
```

FYI `.Offset` goes like so:

```
Range("Cell Reference").Offset(rows, columns)
```

Where 'Cell Reference' can be any cell, like 'A1' or 'D24', rows is the number of rows to offset *to the right* (use negative number to offset to the left), and columns is the number of columns to offset *down* (use negative to offset up). So a value of `.offset(0, 0)` offsets to nowhere.

**EDIT:** You may not use column A to seek the first blank cell; if so, adapt the `offset` values to reflect which cell you want to change the value of. A value of 1 will offset one column right or one row down, and -1 will offset one column *left* or one row *up*.

**ADDITION:** It will be better to use `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` instead of the loop to find the first blank cell. Set the range variable equal to this, and replace the loop with:

```
set rngSeek = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

You can then use `rngSeek` the way described above. (you can rename `rngSeek` to any variable name also).

Comment: What about this function i just found on the microsoft website, is this better than using the while loop?
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

Comment: Yep that will do the same thing - check the addition to my answer for the best way to integrate it

Comment: Yeah I just saw it, I was using column B as that column should always have something in whereas A doesnt. Im trying to go through my script using your offset function which you showed me so that way i dont have to use the select thing. I take it you think this option is better?

Comment: Well, any time you make a computer do something you don't need to do it's wasteful of resources (no matter how small), so I prefer to keep things as concise and direct as possible. One upshot of this method is that whichever cell the user had selected before running this macro will remain unaffected (unlike using .select on a cell). But realistically, whatever YOU find easier is the best method, as you are the one to maintain the code. So do whatever feels most natural to you.

Comment: Well not programming feels perticularly natural to me haha. Okay, how do i do a range of cells with the offset function? I wouldnt have to do them each individually would i?

Comment: Exactly the same - set up a range that is the desired size/shape, then offset by the number of columns/rows. You can call .value on a range of several cells and update them all together. To set a range of multiple cells, use like Range("A1:B4").

Comment: I answered my question so i can show you my current script now after i've edited but it keeps saying expected end with? I dont understand why! Also i wasnt sure how to set a range in the same place as the rngseek so i left that out for the time being.

Comment: Okay i cant answer my own question so i'll have to edit my original question with the new script